# Possible to view parameter values passed to subreport?

Tags: reporting-services

Using Sqlserver 2012.

Say I have a SSRS rdl report "P" that calls several subreports "S1", "S2". 
Just wondering if it is possible to view (in a logfile etc), the parameters and values that P passes to S1 and S2 during report generation.

I know you can view the parameters and values passed to the parent report P in views like ExecutionLog3, but couldn't find any logging of the subreports' parameters.

A work around will be to display the parameter values in the subreports themselves, but this is not ideal. The reports themselves run ok .. the parameters are wanted for diagnostic purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding the logging process to the start of your main dataset in each subreport, that way it will fire only when the subreport is called.

In other words, the dataset for "S1" might look something like...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyLogTable (SubReportName, Parm1, Parm2, ActionDate)
    VALUES ('S1', @p1, @p2, GetDate())

{Your original dataset SQL here}
```

If you parameters are multi-valued then you may have to do some manipulation first but you get the idea I hope.
You could also improve this by using the ID of the subreport from the report server catalogue in case you ever want to join this back to the execution logs.

Comment: thanks. That may be about the best one can do. I might also use sql profiler traces, which may be good enough for my purposes.